# MySQL Select Distinct Question

Tags: mysql, sql, select, distinct, greatest-n-per-group

I want to return all columns from a table, but only for the 'unique' or 'distinct' users.

I want to grab all the distinct users from a table, but return all columns.

I will be sorting the table by a timestamp, so as to grab the 'first' entry of each distinct user.

Any Ideas?

Comment: As far as I know DISTINCT is not for a column but for a returned record. Like if your select like: SELECT A,B,C FROM... then A,B,C as a record will be unique in the result set. I think you'll have to use GROUP BY or select distinct users into an IN (SELECT DISTINCT ...) in the WHERE of the original query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should post the table definition but more or less it should be possible using a `GROUP BY`.

```
SELECT col1, col2, col3, MIN(timestamp)
FROM   users
GROUP BY
       col1, col2, col3
```

If any of your other columns also contains variable data (as they actually should in a normalized table), you have to make a choice on what aggregrate function you wish to use on them.

```
SELECT col1, col2, col3, MAX(var1), AVG(var2), ..., MIN(timestamp)
FROM   users
GROUP BY
       col1, col2, col3
```

Comment: @Wesley - you can't have them all <g>

Comment: OK, not sure about this... here is what I have right now.
`SELECT * FROM userinfoTable INNER JOIN users ON userInfoTable.user_id=users.user_id ORDER BY userInfoTable.uptime ASC;`
Do I just throw a `GROUP BY userInfoTable.user_id` before the `ORDER BY`?

Comment: @Sam Grant - Have you tried it? you should really show us the actual fields involved.

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from table group by userid order by time;
```

Don't forget to rename userid and time to match your column names

Comment: ... that MySQL keeps giving me the creeps. What does that even mean? It's magic

Comment: No other database I know of allows for `SELECT *` along with `GROUP BY`. That has no meaning but selecting an arbitrary value for every column.

Comment: actually it's not such a good idea to ever use * as it decreases performance if you have big databases. You must select only the columns that are needed and them group them, so instead of * there should be userid. My mistake, I've tried to answer fast, great feedback

Comment: Ah, no i didn't mean the asterisk itself. Usually, you cannot select columns that are neither `GROUP BY` columns, nor aggregate functions... But I know this works in MySQL, magically

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using GROUP BY, i.e.

```
SELECT * FROM users GROUP BY id ORDER BY ...
```

Generally it should work, but you haven't mentioned any structure..

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need to group. What you want is select every record in your table that doesn't have another record for the same user with a lesser (or greater) timestamp

```
select * from my_table t1
where not exists (select 1 from my_table t2
                   where t1.user = t2.user
                     and t1.time < t2.time)
```

Be sure to have indexes on `user` and `time` columns

Answer (score 0):

```
select * 
from table a,
(select min(timestampfield) as ts, userid as userid
from table
group by userid) b
where a.userid = b.userid and a.ts = b.ts
```